# css media queries или js?

Tags: javascript, css, адаптивная-верстка

ie 8 не понимает css медиа-запросы.

Нашел скрипт, который решает данную проблему, только этот скрипт довольно-таки объемный.

Почему нельзя просто через js проверять размер body, и, в зависимости от размера, подключать стили?

Почему не используется такой подход?

В чем его минусы?

Comment: Это называется костыль, подобные вещи не очень приветствуются, но, если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то можно и костылять. Работает и ладно.

Comment: я вам сочувствую, печально наблюдать, что некоторые продолжают поддерживать старого осла. Вполне можете через `js` проверять размер видимой части, ничего страшного. Можете скинуть ссылку на этот большой скрипт?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769493/ie8-support-for-css-media-query

Comment: IE8 ? Нет, не слышал

Answer (score 1):

Разница во времени, которое вы потратите на отладку. Если вы ошиблись используя CSS, IDE вам это сразу покажет. А в случае с JavaScript после каждой правки нужно как минимум перезагружать страницу

Answer (score 0):

CSS выполняется быстрее, меньше загружает браузер за счет оптимизации...

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond Вот хорошее решение для старых ИЕ